# what does ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types means

Tags: python, gaussian, pulse, numpy-ufunc

I'm trying to write a gaussian pulse function which you can see in the picture (named g(t)) or below. [Gaussian pulse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZXDk.png)

g(t) = rect(t/T)*exp((-(t-t0)^2)/(sigma)^2)*exp(i*2*pi*f_c*t)

Where -t is the time and my variable for my x axis
-t0,sigma and f_c are variables that can change according to what result you want (I put them as input() in the code)
-T is the interval of time between mesures

I'm using on Jupyter notebook in Python 3.
While trying to write my function, I have this error in the line where I name my var "partie1" : ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32').
I did some research, but none of them work and I'm still unsure of waht exactly this error means.

Here's my code:
#1.Définir la fonction g_t

#1.1 Définir la fonction rect et ces variables

```
T=500
t= np.arange(start=-0.2,stop=0.2,step=(1/T))
for i in range(len(t)):
     if abs(t[i]<=(T/2)):
         rect=1
     else:
         rect=0

#1.2 Définir la partie exponantielle et ces variables
        
i = complex(0,1)
t0 = input('Entrer la valeur de t0')
sigma = input('Entrer la valeur de sigma')
f_c = input('Entrer la valeur de f_c')
partie1 = math.exp((-(t-t0)**2)/((sigma)**2))
partie2 = math.exp((i*2*pi*f_c)*t)

#1.3 Définir la fonction g_t
g_t = partie1*partie2*rect
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: `input` returns a string, so you need to convert those to a numeric type.

Comment: oh ok thank you! I'm used to working with Matlab so I'm new to Python!

Comment: Welcome to Python and to StackOverflow!